# How to add autocomplete suggestions from database under search bar ?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, search

I am new in web programming, so sorry if the following question seems silly. I used JQuery to add auto complete under the search bar, but instead of using hard coded array as a source, I need data from database.

Any help would be appreciated .

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="search..." name = "search"      type="text"
       autocomplete = off id = "autocomplete_search">
        <script>
         $( "#autocomplete_search" ).autocomplete
         (
           {
             source: ["javascript", "java", "c++", "net", "web", "php"]  
           }
         );
        </script>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to get the data

```
source: query()
```

Then the function would call the data.

```
function query(){
    var q;
    $.post('query.php', function(data){
        q = data;
    })
    return q;
}
```

Then your PHP function would be:

```
$data = array();
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM users";
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row){
    array_push($row['firstname'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then you'll have to play around with that. At least it's a start.

[Here's a post on how to write a simple query.](http://imprintedstudios.com/isscriptcode/write-simple-query/)